# Improve Crawl rate

Tags: 2013, crawl

We have  2 wfe, and 2 AS.
We have 18,000 sites worth 500GB of data in 5 content DBs
We have continuous crawl enabled every 15 minutes, but every crawl  takes about 1 hour and 30 minutes.

We have about 7 million searchable items.
We need to improve the crawl rate, in my opinion its too low (4.3)

Question :
How can the crawl rate be improved? Add servers that do only crawling and content processing for example?

[image: http://screencast.com/t/jk3aoIJBbl0]

Comment: Hey Luis! I've been looking at this myself and came across this article about FAST (what's now integrated into SP2013): http://www.chrisweldon.net/blog/2012/09/26/fast-search-thruput-optimization-troubleshooting/

Comment: hey dude, long time no see! :) thanks for that I will read it!

Comment: Indeed! You're welcome, basicly he shows how you can trouble shoot the issue and in his case it had to do with a network bottle neck caused by configurations specific to his system being on a VM, if I'm correct. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using dedicated servers for search. There are guidance on Technet regarding the relatively new "best practice" physical topology called Streamlined Topologies, where one setup is using a dedicated server for search.

Streamlined topologies is an attempt to make the server topology more simple, and configure it based on latency/cpu/ram usage rather than the older topology that was more designed with roles in mind.

You could choose to run a dedicated setup for search to free resources for indexing. In a typical Streamlined setup, it is recommended to scale search out on dedicated servers when going above 2 batch servers (roughly translates to App servers in the old application server topology).

Also read the hardware requirements for search topologies in the article ["Scale search for performance and availability.."](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219628%28v=office.15%29) to be sure that especially your server running index component has enough RAM.

[Streamlined topologies.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219591.aspx#Section1)

[Streamlined topologies topology examples.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/fp123594.aspx)